# How can I set a variable in my workshop module via URL?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I currently have a workshop module that allows users to view a set of objects and then filter them according to a filter widget.

I would like my users to be able to set which filters are applied via URL such that they can quickly apply their default filters.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a variable for each filter you would like the user to be able to apply via URL.
2. Promote the variable so that it can be update via the URL.
   [image]
3. Update the filter output to use the variables you created above.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the promoted variables described in the answer above, specifically for the case of saving and re-using Filter state, you can enable the [State Saving](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/state-saving/) feature for users of your app, which allows them to snapshot and save specific application state as a separate Foundry resource. You can then share the link or bookmark or re-open from a folder without worrying about the "wiring" of variables and URL parameters.